# Builder pattern on RequestBody

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-boot

I have been developing spring boot rest api service, this is one of my rest controller method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "manager", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateManager(@RequestBody Managers manager,
            @RequestParam(value = "sid", required = true, defaultValue = "") String sid) throws TimeoutException, SocketTimeoutException, SocketException {

        final Integer managerId = checkSession(sid);
        final String result = managerController.validateManagerData(managerId, manager.getName(), manager.getSurname(), manager.getPassword());
        return result;

    }
```

Manager controller it's the validator class(for example check email on null reference)

```
if (name != null) {
            if (!GMoikaStringUtils.isValidStringLength(50, name)) {
                throw new InvalidUserInputException("Wrong name format", CLASS_NAME, "validateManagerData", params);
            }
        }
        if (surname != null) {
            if (!GMoikaStringUtils.isValidStringLength(50, surname)) {
                throw new InvalidUserInputException("Wrong surname format", CLASS_NAME, "validateManagerData", params);
            }
        }
```

After validation of data i call `Manager service class`

```
public JsonObject updateManager(Integer managerId, String name, String surname, String password) {
            Managers manager = managerRepository.findOne(managerId);
            if (name != null) {
                manager.setName(name);
            }
            if (surname != null) {
                manager.setSurname(surname);
            }
            if (password != null) {
                manager.setPassword(password);
            }
            managerRepository.save(manager);
            return manager.toJson();
        }
```

My qustion is, i pass a lot of params into methods(name,surname,email,password etc) if i change the order , i will save wrong params into db. The first decision is to pass Manager object instead of manager params.
But in this case i will have the following scenario:

```
public JsonObject updateManager(Integer managerId,Managers manager2) {
            Managers manager = managerRepository.findOne(managerId);
            if (manager2.name != null) {
                manager.setName(name);
            }
            if (manager2.surname != null) {
                manager.setSurname(surname);
            }
            if (manager2.password != null) {
                manager.setPassword(password);
            }
            managerRepository.save(manager);
            return manager.toJson();
        }
```

Two managers in one method . It's look like difficul to understand which one should be saved into db

The second decision is to use Builder pattern(BP), but i don't know is it good practise to use BP with ORM and how to do it better?

Comment: Why do you not use built-in validation annotations? As far as I see you are not validating **manager** with complicated logic but standart null check.

Comment: I have, i need to use my validation(without annotations)  in order to throw specific exception

Comment: You can throw your specific exception with annotations too. One way is this: Catch the validation exception in an **advice** and do it what you want with it(logging, throwing another exception, sending error response as request response etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `managers` entity should be `manager`.
Keep the singular from to represent a class which an instance represents an individual "thing".

> Two managers in one method . It's look like difficul to understand
>   which one should be saved into db

With this too generic naming for parameters, yes :

```
public JsonObject updateManager(Integer managerId, Manager manager2) {
```

Just be more specific, it should be fine :

```
public JsonObject updateManager(Integer managerId, Manager managerDataToSave) {
```

Or if it may make more sense, introduce a custom class to be still more specific:

For example : `ManagerInfoToUpdate` that will contain the information to update (name,surname,email, etc...).

And use it in this way :

```
public JsonObject updateManager(Integer managerId, Manager ManagerInfoToUpdate) {
```

> The second decision is to use Builder pattern(BP), but i don't know is
>   it good practise to use BP with ORM and how to do it better?

ORM such as Hibernate uses reflection to create entity instance. So, it requires a no-arg constructor.
 It defeats the purpose of the Builder pattern.
You should probably not use it for Hibernate entities.